# Dynamic binding in static method php

Tags: php, static-methods, dynamic-binding

```
class A
{
  static function get_name_derived_class()
  {
      //This function must return the name of the real class
      //Is it possible without insert a methon in B class?
  {
}

class B extends A
{

}

B::test()
```

I'd like to have a static methon in base class which returns the name of real (derived) class, without insert a specific method in it. is it possible?
thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

class A
{
    static function test()
    {
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
}

echo B::test();
```

Requires PHP >= 5.3.0. See PHP's manual entry on [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)